# Data-xyz returning an empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following to create custom sharing buttons on my site. I can pass the URL via a data-url attribute and it works, however I have a data-tweet attribute that is returning an empty string to the console when I'm checking the code.

```
//sharing links
setShareLinks();
function socialWindow(url) {
var left = (screen.width - 570) / 2;
var top = (screen.height - 570) / 2;
var params = "menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,width=570,height=570,top=" + top + ",left=" + left;
window.open(url,"NewWindow",params);
}

function setShareLinks() {
var pageURL = encodeURIComponent($('#share').attr("data-url"));
var tweet = $('#share').attr("data-tweet");
console.log(pageURL);
console.log(tweet)

jQuery(".social-share.facebook").on("click", function() {
    url = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" + pageURL;
    socialWindow(url);
});

jQuery(".social-share.twitter").on("click", function() {
    url = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=" + pageURL + "&text=" + tweet;
    socialWindow(url);
});

jQuery(".social-share.linkedin").on("click", function() {
    url = "https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=" + pageURL;
    socialWindow(url);
})
};
```

And the html is here

```
<div class="links" id="share" data-tweet="test" data-url="<?php echo URLROOT.'/ships-logs/'.date('jS-F-Y', strtotime($data['pageData']->post_createdOn)); ?>">
<div class="btn social-share facebook text-white shadow-sm mt-1">
<div class="mr-2" style="display:inline;">
<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
</div>
<div style="display:inline;">
Share on Facebook
</div>
</div>
<div class="btn social-share twitter text-white shadow-sm mt-1">
<div class="mr-2" style="display:inline;">
<i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
</div>
<div style="display:inline;">
Share on Twitter
</div>
</div>
<div class="btn social-share linkedin text-white shadow-sm mt-1">
<div class="mr-2" style="display:inline;">
<i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
</div>
<div style="display:inline;">
Share on LinkedIn
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong? I'm sure I have a typo or don't quite understand what the code is doing.

Comment: Provided that HTML is in the DOM when you do `var tweet = $('#share').attr("data-tweet");`, you'll definitely get the value. (Unless there's a *second* `#share` element earlier in the DOM than the one you've shown.)

Comment: Seems to be working fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/zjL024u3/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You hit the nail on the head; a quick search through my code and I had added some more share buttons in the header!

Answer (score 0):

My code above is working - as per @T.J Crowder's comment I had a second 'share element in the DOM which was causing issues.